# Counting consecutive letter pairs in string

Tags: c#, string, count

I'm creating a diagram (frequency for 2 letters (like aa,ac,bh,is) in the string)
assume there are no special characters, no whitespaces in the text. only alphabets.

```
        string text;
        char char1[]= {a,b,c,....z};   //26 alphabets
        int[][] count=null;
        for (i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 26; j++)
            {
                count[i][j] = text.Count(char[i]char[j]); <---- this is the problem

            }
        }
```

so count[][] would hv number of occurrences of all pair of alphabets in the text
like aa 10,ab 5 n so on...

the statement in for loop is just to give an idea of what is needed to be done.
i was thinking of using foreach loop but we cant read two characters in foreach.
I can use switch but in switch will have to write 26x26=676 cases lol

got stuck here..
how do i read 2 characters from the string ? and count their occurrences in the whole string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this using [Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
        string text = "aabbcc";
        char[] char1 =  { 'a', 'b', 'c' , 'z' };   //26 alphabets
        int[,] count = new int[char1.Length, char1.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < char1.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < char1.Length; j++)
            {
                count[i,j] = Regex.Matches(text, string.Concat(char1[i],char1[j]), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Count;
            }
        }
```

Note I put the RegexOption as ignore case, but you can remove it if you want case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

If you use LINQ it becomes an easy solution. There is a Split method on string which you can use to split string in array and iterate through it.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string text = "this is a ss and mm is not to be count an me"; //Input string

        // Find only 2 letter strings
        List<string> allTwoLetters = text.Split(new Char[]{' '}).Where(x=>x.Length==2).ToList();


        //Find all Distinct strings in two letter string list
        List<string> distinctStrings = allTwoLetters.Distinct().ToList();

        //dictionary to hold result
        Dictionary<string,int> letterCount = new Dictionary<string,int>();

        //Iterate throug each string in distinct string and count how many such strings are there i two letter list of strings
        foreach(string current in distinctStrings)
        {
            letterCount.Add(current,allTwoLetters.Where(p=>p == current).ToList().Count);
        }

        //Output values
        foreach(var kvp in letterCount)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + " - "+ kvp.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont know Linq :/
n dont want to use something i dont understand...
but thanks a lot for ur help :)

Comment: @VishalSingh that does not bode well for your future in software development.

Comment: @VishalSingh, don't be afraid to try something you don't understand, that's how you get to understand it!

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the LINQ answer but without LINQ. This uses a dictionary with the two letter pairs as the key, and an int as the count.

```
string text ="asasdfasdf";
        char[] alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".ToCharArray();
        Dictionary<string,int> letterCombos = new Dictionary<string,int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++)
            {
                letterCombos.Add(alphabet[i] + alphabet[j].ToString(), 0);
            }
        }
        char[] textCharArray=text.ToCharArray();
        for (int i =0;i<text.Length-1;i++)
        {
            string partial = textCharArray[i] + textCharArray[i + 1].ToString();
            letterCombos[partial]++;
        }
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kp in letterCombos)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(kp.Key +": "+kp.Value);
        }
```